# How to show $\|e^{ikx}-e^{ix}\|_{L^{1}}$ does not converge to $0$ when $k\rightarrow\infty$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral, complex-integration

I am in the middle of a proof, and I need to show that

> $$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|e^{ikx}-e^{ix}|dx\ \text{does not converge to}\ 0.$$

For now, I got this:

\begin{align*}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|e^{ikx}-e^{ix}|dx=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|e^{ix}||e^{ix(k-1)}-1|dx&=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|e^{ix(k-1)}-1|dx\\
&=\int_{-\pi(k-1)}^{\pi(k-1)}\dfrac{1}{k-1}|e^{iy}-1|dy,\ \text{replacing}\ y:=x(k-1)\\
&=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|e^{iy}-1|dy,\ \text{since}\ e^{iy}\ \text{is}\ 2\pi-\text{periodic}.
\end{align*}

Now we get rid of $k$, but what should I do to show the RHS is not zero?

Thank you!

Comment: can you explain where did the $\dfrac{1}{k-1}$ go ?

Comment: @infinity since $e^{iy}$ is $2\pi-$periodic, the integral can also be reduced to $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}$, and there are $(k-1)$ copies of $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}$ so we have $\int_{-\pi(k-1)}^{\pi(k-1)}=(k-1)\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}$ and thus these two $(k-1)$'s cancel

Comment: Got it, nice. i will try to think now about your question :)

Comment: @infinity thank you! :)

Comment: just wrote it, what do you think?

Comment: @infinity I think it is perfect and brilliant.

Comment: The RHS isn’t zero because $y \longmapsto |e^{iy}-1|$ is a continuous nonnegative function that only has one root on $(-\pi,\pi)$ (eg, it is greater than $\sqrt{2}$ when $|y| \geq \pi/2$ so the integral is at least $\pi/\sqrt{2}$).

Comment: @Mindlack Thank you for this alternative solution! This is also inspiring.

Comment: @Mindlack by the way, the integral is at least $2\sqrt{2}\pi$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuoing your last equation:

$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |e^{iy}-1| dy = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |cos(y) +isin(y) -1|dy =\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sqrt{(cos(y)-1)^2 +sin(y)^2)}dy =\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sqrt{2-2cos(y)}dy=2\sqrt{2}\int_0^\pi \sqrt{1-cos(y)}dy $.

Now, $\int_0^{\pi} \sqrt{1-cos(y)}dy =\int_0^{\pi} \sqrt{1-cos(y)} \dfrac{\sqrt{1+cos(y)}}{\sqrt{1+cos(y)}}dy=\int_0^{\pi} \dfrac{\sqrt{1-cos^2(y)}}{\sqrt{1+cos(y)}} dy$

Using $sin^2(y)+cos^2(y)=1$ in the last equation we get

$= \int_0^{\pi} \dfrac{\sqrt{sin^2(y)}}{\sqrt{1+cos(y)}}dy = \int_0^{\pi} \dfrac{sin(y)}{\sqrt{1+cos(y)}}dy$

Now using the substitution $u = 1+cos(y)$ we get

$= -\int_2^0\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{u}}du =\int_0^2\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{u}}du= 2\sqrt{u}|_0^2 = 2\sqrt{2}$.

Returnning to our equation we get :

$$ 2\sqrt{2}\int_0^\pi \sqrt{1-cos(y)}dy= 8$$

Comment: Thank you so much! Perfect answer.

Comment: @infinity: There’s a problem, the modulus is the square root of $(\cos{y}-1)^2+(\sin{y})^2$.

Comment: @Mindlack oops. you are right.. i will try to fix it.

Comment: oh I also found that the last equality you should have $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}2\cos(y)$, instead of $+1$.

Comment: @JacobsonRadical also right.. sorry.

Comment: @infinity nonon, its fine. let's work it out.

Comment: ok so we have $\sqrt(2) \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sqrt{cos(y)}dy = 2\sqrt{2}\int_0^{\pi}\sqrt{cos(y)} dy$

Comment: @infinity then wolfram alpha said the integral is not zero, but how could we prove it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105253/discussion-between-infinity-and-jacobsonradical).

Answer (score 1):

The primitive of $e^{ikx}-e^{ix} $ tends to $ \frac{1-e^{ix}}{i}$ uniformly, this is not the zero function